# Webpack: Can you include a set of global styles used when compiling preprocessed styles with a loader?

Tags: webpack, stylus

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, and can't seem to find anything on it. I've got webpack setup with stylus loaders, allowing the `.styl` files to be imported in the js modules directly.

The issue I'm facing is that the preprocessor context starts and ends with that single `.styl` file.

I'd like to be able to define global styles, ex:

```
// global.styl

$brand-var1 = #000;
$brand-var2 = #FFF;
```

Which can be relied upon by the individual `.styl` files imported:

```
// my-comp.styl

button {
  background-color: $brand-var1;
}
```

by the js component

```
// my-comp.js

import './my-comp.styl'
...
```

I'd like to avoid having to `@import` or `@require` the global styles in each and every stylus file which would use it.

Is there any webpack config which would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack 2: in rules you can pass `import` option to `stylus-loader` to load styles globally:

```
  {
    test: /\.styl$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'stylus-loader',
        options: {
          import: [
            resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/global.styl')
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
```

---

In webpack I used it this way:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  stylus: {
    import: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles/globals.styl')
    ]
  }
}
```